# How to loop through and return any value if it is found inside any other column within a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to loop through and return any value if it is found inside any other column, and store it in a list using pandas? It doesn't matter how many times it is found, just that it is found at least one more time in a different column. If the value has repeated within the same column, it's not included in the list. Each value must be compared to every other value except from within the same column, if that makes sense.

> ```
> combined_insp = []
> test_df = pd.DataFrame({'area_1': ['John', 'Mike', 'Mary', 'Sarah'],
>                         'area_2': ['John', 'Bob', 'Mary', 'Mary'],
>                         'area_3': ['Jane', 'Sarah', 'David', 'Michael'],
>                         'area_4': ['Diana', 'Mike', 'Bill', 'Bill']})
> ```

Expected output would be

> combined_insp = ['John', 'Mary', 'Sarah', 'Mike']

Comment: Which would be the key column and which would be the lookup columns? For example: do you want to check if each element of area1 is present in area2/3/4?

Comment: Thinking about the logic, it should be from any column to any other column, if that make sense. The names will shift around depending on the time. Now that I think about it I will also need to return the column name along those so I will probably have to use a dictionary to store the data, but that's a question for another time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `itertools` and set algebra:

```
from itertools import combinations

combined_insp = set.union(*[set(test_df[c1]).intersection(test_df[c2]) 
                            for (c1, c2) in combinations(test_df.columns, 2)])
```

For each unique combination of columns we take the *intersection* of the values. Then we take the *union* of all the results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.apply(set)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for removing duplicated elements in each list. Then You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten all elements to one list. At the end, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for counting elements and returning elements that have `count > 1`. *(type of the result of `Counter` is `dict` and you can iterate over `dict` with `dict.items()`.)*

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
combined_insp = [k for k,v in Counter(chain.from_iterable(test_df.apply(set))).items() if v>1]
print(combined_insp)
```

---

```
['Sarah', 'Mike', 'Mary', 'John']
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# pd.melt to flatted the table, then use groupby and take the names that appear more than once

g=df.melt(value_name='area').drop_duplicates().groupby('area')
[key for key, group in g if (group.count() > 1).all() ]
```

```
['John', 'Mary', 'Mike', 'Sarah']
```

Comment: This one doesn't work because it includes Bill. We want to exclude names that appear within the same column more than once.

Comment: @AnthonyStokes, corrected the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = df.melt().drop_duplicates()['value'].value_counts()
answer = counts[counts > 1].index.to_list()
```